# How to Build a Git based updatesystem for a multiple hosting-environment in combination with Directadmin?

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, opencart, directadmin

**Situation**
We are hosting multiple webshops (open-cart) on multiple servers. Every webshop has its own user environment in DirectAdmin so we can connect a domain to the webshop. The webshops are mostly unique but they can differ in code due to some custom modules we develop for them. The code base is for every webshop the same. Currently updates are excecuted with DirectAdmin (Installatron/FTP). This is a time consuming job and sensitive to errors.

**Goal** I want to improve te development structure to connect it to Git (Bitbucket). I build a local development server that is connected to Bitbucket. This is working well. We want to connect the different webshops with Bitbucket but we want to control the updates our selves to have control over which webshops are getting a new update and when.

**What we have done so far..** I build a new backend and frontend by which I import the different webshops through the DirectAdmin API. I have written a shell script I can upload to the webshops. This shell script is creating a new repository in the webshops' public_html and adds a new remote from Bitbucket. I then try to merge the origin from bitbucket with the existing repo on the server. The point is to have no merge conflicts because everything is handled through the new backend. I first try to reset the repo to origins'master branch, but then important (custom) files are lost like the .htaccess files and custom modules that are not included (yet) in the codebase on Bitbucket. Now it is getting pretty complex due to the diversity of the webshops. I cannot find a solution to automaticly merge the origin/master on the shop without losing files and custom modules.

**Tried solutions**

- Different merge strategies (theirs/ours)
- Working with `git reset --hard`

**What I'm looking for** I'm looking for alternatives to set up a proper development structure that fits our server-structure (DirectAdmin /user-packages) and being able to connect this to Git (Bitbucket).

So I hope that someone has been in this case before and have a great Idea! Thanks alot ;)

Comment: I know people sometimes put Git repos on public facing websites, and deploy by pulling down a branch, but, in my experience I prefer to have separate deploy scripts that place the exact files you need in the correct place on the server. With a separate deploy this sort of problem goes away. You could also make the deploy dynamic such that it deploys different configs per customer, based on some similarly named config files per customer in the repo.

Comment: And, I apologize for the (probably) unhelpful comment. I suspect it's the exact opposite of what you're looking for in your answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! :) Every fresh thought on this matter is more than welcome. About the deploy scripts, how do you combine that with Git? Is it for example recommended to store a repo on one place an then deploy from there? (In that case I will use git, but my merge problems are gone).

Comment: I'm not sure combining it with Git is the right way to think about it, at least for the concept I'm describing. Imagine you have a bunch of code on your machine. And maybe a folder for deployment scripts. When you run a script, it does "stuff" which probably includes copying the deployable files from your code directory onto another server (the public web server). The deploy script may take an argument per customer so it knows which customer specific files to copy. That is independent of Git. Now, put all your code and deploy scripts into a Git repo for tracking changes.

Comment: I think that I'm to much focussed on Git. Maybe it is indeed better to seperate git from the deployment and work with copying files through deployment scripts. I think I have a new lead to discover :) Thanks for pushing me in this direction :)